# Bitcoin regulation by country

Tags: legal, regulation

I am looking for a straightforward Bitcoin regulation list accepted in each country. About how it's legal, illegal or denied and if it's legal is there any specific rules in each country?

Answer (score 1):

There is a page on Wikipedia that tracks [Bitcoin legality by country or territory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legality_of_bitcoin_by_country_or_territory).

Another one can be found on [Coin.dance](https://coin.dance/poli#legalitybycountry).